# MCMC in a frequentist setting

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, expectation-maximization, metropolis-hastings, frequentist

I have been trying to get a sense of the different problems in frequentist settings where MCMC is used. I am familiar that MCMC (or Monte Carlo) is used in fitting GLMMs and in maybe Monte Carlo EM algorithms. Are there more frequentist problems where MCMC is used?

Comment: When a Bayesian model can also be construed as a frequentist model (e.g., all priors are flat), the posterior mode is the MLE. So, you can use MCMC to do MLE, although that might not be a very good way to do it.

Comment: @Kodiologist Sure. Although, it is likely we are interested in the posterior mean (if working under least squares loss function), so we won't even try to find the MLE. But I see what you mean.

Comment: @Kodiologist but why would frequentist do that? First, this would lead to multiple conceptual problems (assuming that parameter is r.v., how to interpret HDI's etc.). Second, if frequentist would use it simply instead of optimization algorithm to find point estimate, why would he do so since it's a very inefficient way if you are only after point estimate...

Comment: @Tim Like I said, it might not be a very good way to do it.

Comment: I came across this by accident, but thought this a useful topic. If I'm not mistaken, monte carlo methods are generally concerned with sampling from a target distribution that one may, or may not, be able to sample directly from. The shift between Bayesian & Frequentist is interpretation of data as RVs or paramters are RVs (as stated by @Tim). So it seems to me that MC methods are neither "bayesian" nor "frequentist". It's rather the philosophy that is applied to their use that creates a distinction. Would this be a correct assessment?

Comment: @Jon Monte Carlo methods find use in Bayesian problems because posterior distributions are often difficult to sample from. I asked this question to see where else MC methods maybe useful outside of the Bayesian work. Perhaps I shouldn't have used "frequentist" in the title. I will add that MC methods themselves are inherently "frequentist" since prior belief is not enforced on the drawn samples, and sample averages are usually used.

Comment: @Greenparker, I understand the use of MC methods in a bayesian setting.  Can you add support to your latter statement? How are MC methods "inherently 'frequentist'"? I'll add to this a scenario, if a frequentist and bayesian enter a room, and each needs to simulate $x_1, ..., x_n \sim Unif(0,1)$, and find the empirical average of those samples, do they each make different assumptions or approaches in simulation?

Comment: @Jon The context I usually work in, "Monte Carlo" refers to estimating an expectation integral with a sample average.  Suppose the goal is to estimate (say) the mean of a $Unif(0,1)$, and samples $x_1, \dots, x_n$ are drawn from this distribution. These samples then act as data and in order to estimate the mean of the distribution, we use the sample average. This seems inherently frequentist. The simulation of $x_1, \dots, x_n$ is only one part of Monte Carlo which is neither Bayesian nor frequentist. But choosing to take the sample average as the estimator seems frequentist.

Comment: @Greenparker, so in classical MC, you may have the situation $E[h(x)]  = \int h(x) f(x) dx \approx \frac{1}{n}\sum^n x_i$ where $x_i \sim f$ and $f$ is some instrumental distribution. If I am following your logic, the (direct) sampling from $f$ is neither bayesian nor frequentist, but the use of the empirical mean would then make this a frequentist estimator. Is this interpretation of your logic correct?

Comment: @Jon (I think you missed an $h$ in the summation) But yes, that is exactly my point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated in the many comments, Markov Chain Monte Carlo is a special case of the Monte Carlo method, which is designed to approximate quantities related with a distribution via pseudo-random number simulation. As such, it has no connection with a particular statistical paradigm and the earliest instances of the method, as in Metropolis et al.  (1953), were unrelated with statistics, Bayesian or frequentist. If anything these methods are naturally "frequentist" (an ill-defined category anyway) in that they rely on the stabilisation of the frequencies or averages towards the expectation as the number of simulations increases, aka the Law of Large Numbers.

It is therefore possible within non-Bayesian complex problems to use MCMC methods to replace intractable integrals. Check for instance

1. the optimisation of likelihoods with no closed form expressions, as in latent variable and random effect models. The EM algorithm may fail to work because of an intractable "E" step, in which case the expectation need be replaced by a Monte Carlo or a [Markov Chain Monte Carlo approximation](http://www.cs.au.dk/~asger/JCGS08.pdf). With a [possible evaluation](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/0094965031000147704) of the error. Or it may fail to work because of an intractable "M" step, in which case the maximisation can sometimes be replaced by a Markovian maximisation procedure as in [simulated annealing](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1018594320699). Or using [Gibbs steps](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.55.4287&rep=rep1...pdf).
2. simulated inference methods in econometrics, as the [simulated method of moments](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/moments.pdf), [indirect inference](https://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/economics/papers/2015/GII_July_22_2015.pdf), [empirical likelihood](http://www.mit.edu/~vchern/ch_qbe.pdf).
3. approximations of likelihoods with [intractable normalising constants](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03331) such as Ising, Potts, and other Markov random fields models, using for instance [exchange algorithms](https://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/doubly_intractable.pdf).
4. [frequentist goodness-of-fit tests](http://www.ims.nus.edu.sg/Programs/mcmc/files/besag_tl.pdf), which may require computations of coverage probabilities, [$p$_values](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3751), powers, for sufficient or insufficient statistics with no closed-form density, or conditional on ancillary statistics. Take the example of [testing for independence](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.3751) in (large) contingency tables (or deriving [the maximum likelihood estimator](http://calvino.polito.it/~pistone/preprints_html/rapallo1.pdf)).
5. again in econometrics, [Laplace type estimators](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407603001003), "which include means and quantiles of quasi-posterior distributions defined as transformations of general nonlikelihood-based statistical criterion functions, such as those in GMM, nonlinear IV, empirical likelihood, and minimum distance methods" (Chernozhukov and Hong, 2003), rely on MCMC algorithms.